# Angular bindings in the HTML set using ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My basic use-case is this - When a particular route is hit (`#/abc`) I need to make a POST call to the server and render the HTML sent as a response. Since the HTML depends on the server call, I did not favor writing this logic into `$routeProvider.when`.

My solution -

- Open the route
- Load a blank view in the ng-view (used in the other parts of app)
- The blank view contains a div with `<div ng-bind-html=responseHtml></div>`
- In the controller, make a `$http.post` and with the data returned, I set the above expression to `$scope.responseHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);`

This is working perfectly fine, however, I am unable to set any bindings in the responseHtml.

The accompanying JSFiddle is here - http://jsfiddle.net/prakhar1989/LX26M/2/

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is the correct way to do it (this is my first Ng app). Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made this for you: http://jsfiddle.net/BgW3u/

You are passing the HTML to the directive and the related scope and it will `$compile` it.

```
app.directive("ngCompile", function($compile){
    return {
        scope: {
            "ngCompile": "=",
            "ngCompileScope": "="
        },        
        link: function($scope, $element){                    
            $scope.compile = function(){
                $element.html($scope.ngCompile);  
                $compile($element.contents())($scope.ngCompileScope);
            }            
            $scope.$watch("ngCompile",function(){
               $scope.compile();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

OR without isolated scope:

```
app.directive('ngCompile', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngCompile, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```